# OpenVPN CE LDAP with Google disable other certificates?

Tags: ldap, config, openvpn

I have an openvpn CE running with slef certified signed certificates.
I wanted to add also Google LDAP functionnality.
So i did.
But its seems i cannot use anymore my old certificates as it asks for a Username/Password now there is LDAP configured.

Is there a way to have both authentication process working at the same time ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question was not clear.

Is there a way to bypass LDAP Authentication for some users on OpenVPN CE ?
I want my network server to connect automatically, using certs, but not LDAP.

Thanks !